# Receive an array of custom error message blade laravel (Array to string conversion)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to get an array of the custom error message in view for specific filed

**controller**

```
$rules = ['user_Name' => 'required|max:40',
              'image' => 'required',
              'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg,bmp|max:8000',
             ];

 // To get name of all image file and display in it in error message 
    if($request->hasfile('image')){  
      $validationArrayImage = array(); 
      $validationArraySize = array();
      $validationArrayType = array();;

      foreach($request->imageas $key => $file){           

        // check file extension for image type
        if($file->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'jpeg' &&
           $file->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'png' && 
           $file->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'jpg' &&
           $file->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'svg' &&
           $file->getClientOriginalExtension() != 'bmp'){


           $validationArrayImage['image.'.$key.'.image'] = 'The ' .  $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' not an image file.';
           $validationArrayType['image.'.$key.'.mimes'] = 'The ' .  $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' must be a file of type: jpeg, png, jpg, svg, bmp.';

        }

        // check file size for image size
        if($file->getSize() >= 8000000){

             $validationArraySize['image.'.$key.'.max'] = 'The ' .  $file->getClientOriginalName() . ' may not be greater than 8 Megabytes.';
           }

      }



      // check names array if it empty or not
      if(!empty($validationArrayType) || !empty($validationArraySize) || !empty($validationArrayImage)){

        // but all names in custom error, message 

       $messages = [
             $validationArrayImage,
             $validationArrayType,
             $validationArraySize,
              ];
       //dd($messages);
      }   

    } 



 if(!empty($messages)){
              $result = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
              /*foreach ($messages as $message) {
                dump($message);                     <--- Here I can see the array 
             }
            dd("stop");*/

           }
           else{ 
               $result = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
                //dd('$result');
           }
```

In the dump function, I can see all custom messages but why I get their empty array?
[image]

I have try this but I got `error exception Array to string conversion`

```
               if(!empty($messages)){
              $result = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
              $errors = $result->errors();
              foreach ($errors->get('image.*') as $message) {
                dump($message);
            }
            dd("stop");
               //dd($result);
           }
           else{ 
               $result = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
                //dd('$result');
           }
```

In balde I have to try to get all message in the array but also I got `error exception Array to string conversion`
**View balde**

```
                        <!-- To get error message for multi file -->
                        @if (!empty($messages)))
                        <h1>There is an error in your input array</h1>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach($messages as $errors)
                            @foreach($errors as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                        @else
                        <strong>Not array</strong>
                        @endif
```

Also, I have try this with the same error `error exception Array to string conversion`

```
<!-- To get error message for multi  -->
                            @if ($errors->has('Bank_Logo.*'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" style="display: block;" role="alert">
                                @foreach($errors->get('Bank_Logo.*') as $errors)
                                @foreach($errors as $error)
                                <strong>{{ $error }}</strong>
                                @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                            </span>
                            @endif
```

I'm trying to get all error messages with the error name for each file.

**Any I idea how to get all error message array to view ?**

Laravel version 5.8

Answer (score 1):

With the custom rule defined, you might use it in your controller validation like so :

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
       'f_name' => 'required|min:8',
       'l_name' => 'required',
   ],
   [
    'f_name.required'=> 'Your First Name is Required', // custom message
    'f_name.min'=> 'First Name Should be Minimum of 8 Character', // custom message
    'l_name.required'=> 'Your Last Name is Required' // custom message
   ]
);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I need to this arrays to custom message in custom rule defined```$validationArrayImage,$validationArrayType,$validationArraySize,``` but still, get this error ```Array to string conversion``` when I add a custom message like you do it works but I want to replace it with arrays and received in view, Also, I cannot use rule before if statement because in if statement it fills the array with a custom message

Comment: The problem was in ```$result = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);``` the message argument should be an array not 2 dimensional array, So I change 3 array ```$validationArrayImage, $validationArrayType, $validationArraySize,``` to one array wtich is ```$message ```  Thanks all.